# Multithreading a GUI using backgroundworkers

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, user-interface

There is 2 Backgroundworkers in my project:

**BGW1:** the first worker is used to read data from a controller and convert the data into the right format

**BGW2:** the second worker is used to pass the converted data and objects to the GUI using the `ReportProgress` functionality

The entire process needs to be as real time as possible and the messages are coming approx every 0.5 ms. The MainThread becomes flustered pretty quick when it has to update 800 points every 5-10 ms.

This causes the GUI to become unresponsive if i update at a faster rate than 10fps.

A solution i have found online, is this:
[Alternate Way of Multithreaded GUI](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21927/An-Alternate-Way-of-Writing-a-Multithreaded-GUI-in)

I have tryed to adopt this methodology to my background workers by setting

```
        // Prevent the framework from checking what thread the GUI is updated from.
        theMainForm.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

in the main form. This allows me to update the gui from a seperate thread not the main thread, from what i understand.
Using this line in the main should mean that i can access the GUI elements from other threads that arent the main thread, and i dont need to use `ReportProgress`
to update the Chart, so i tried updating the Chart from my `DoWork` portion of **BGW2**.

The update works from `DoWork`, but it seems to still just refer the Data to the MainThread and that thread then updates the chart, which results in an unusable GUI again.

Do i have to get rid of the backgroundworkers completly and only use Threads for the solution from the link to work? Or is there some sort of trick to getting this method to work with backgroundworkers.

Comment: You will see the bulk of your gains by simply doing long-running operations on a thread that isn't the UI thread.  Adding additional background threads will only be helpful if you have disparate tasks that can be completed in parallel without inter-dependencies on each other or shared resources.

Comment: Instead of background workers you should use Tasks but that will only take care of processing the incoming events asynchronously eg with an asynchronous event handler. To reduce the update frequency of the UI, you need to throttle the incoming events, eg using Throttle from Reactive Extensions as [shown here](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc30) to bunlde and process events only every X milliseconds or Y events

Comment: This is the 3rd most common threading bug, a *fire-hose* problem.  Unlike the top 2 it is pretty easy to diagnose, Task Manager can show your UI thread burning 100% core.   By setting CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to *false*, you now also enable those other bugs, threading races and deadlock.  The completely undebuggable kind.   Fantastically Bad Idea.  If you can't keep a human eye occupied with the UI thread, it only takes 20 updates/second before it starts turning into a blur, then you are doing it wrong.  It just doesn't make any sense to do it more often.

Comment: @Hans Passant the UI thread doesn't burn at 100% it just goes high enough that user input becomes delayed, due the amount of data that is being passed to the main thread. That is why I have currently limited the application to 10fps. it seems to be the sweet spot where the GUI stays 100% interactive and the chart still is fluent enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, don't update that often. Just stick to a fixed refresh rate, and use a `ConcurrentQueue` to pass the data points between the `BackgroundWorker` that reads the data, and the GUI that renders it. A simple `Timer` should work well enough - every five seconds, read everything out of the `ConcurrentQueue` and update the chart.

Don't update the UI from multiple threads. There's a reason why the checks are there.

Comment: @rwank Yeah, and what's the GUI thread doing in the meantime? And any other thread where you forget you're actually on another thread? There's reasons why accesses to the GUI are limited to the GUI thread, multi-threading is *hard*.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to [enforce the events being handled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? This will empty the events queue so the form becomes responsible for the user. Nevertheless you better go with updating the GUI at a fixed rate, as pointed out by Luaan.

Answer (score 0):

One background worker really is enough.

The expensive parts of this operation are;

1. Synchronizing back to the UI thread
2. Blocking the worker while you do it.

The solve the performance issue, minimise #1. Don't post every item, post many items every `x` milliseconds.

In fact, I'd recommend not using a background worker at all - the `ReportProgress` event blocks your worker thread.

Comment: the 10Fps i have mentioned above is the fastest update rate i can use with `ReportProgress`, hence why im looking for a workaround that lets me directly update the chart without having to interfer in the mainthread